# Custom Class std::map Weird Behavior

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I'm getting a weird behavior when searching for a key in a map with a custom class I created as keys.

It seems that it doesn't find the keys although they are present in the map.

Anyone knows the reason for this?

Code (can run it [here](http://cpp.sh/6u3pu)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef short int dimension;

class Point {
public:
    Point() : m_x(0), m_y(0) {}

    Point(const Point &other) : m_x(other.m_x), m_y(other.m_y) {};

    Point(dimension x, dimension y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}

    bool operator<(const Point &other) const {
        if (m_x < other.m_x) return true;
        return (m_y < other.m_y);
    }

private:
    dimension m_x;
    dimension m_y;
};


int main() {
    map<Point, bool> points = {{Point(0, 2), true},
                               {Point(1, 1), true},
                               {Point(2, 4), true}};

    cout << (points.find(((points.begin())->first)) == points.end()) << endl;
    cout << (points.find((next(points.begin()))->first) == points.end()) << endl;
    cout << (points.find((next(next(points.begin())))->first) == points.end()) << endl;

    cout << (points.find(Point(0, 2)) == points.end()) << endl;
    cout << (points.find(Point(1, 1)) == points.end()) << endl;
    cout << (points.find(Point(2, 4)) == points.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: Your `<` is not a strict weak ordering; you have both `{3,4} < {4,2}` and `{4,2} < {3,4}`, and they can't both be ordered before the other

Comment: FWIW, when writing a comparator for yourself, use `std::tie` to wrap the members in a tuple so the code becomes `return std::tie(lhs.mem1, lhs.mem2, ..., lhs.memN) op std::tie(rhs.mem1, rhs.mem2, ..., rhs.memN);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `operator<` is flawed:

```
bool operator<(const Point &other) const {
    if (m_x < other.m_x) return true;
    return (m_y < other.m_y);
}
```

For example

```
 {0, 3} < {1, 2}  -> true
```

but

```
 {1, 2} < {0,3}   -> true
```

The `operator<` must implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). You forgot to consider the case when `(m_x > other.m_x)` which should result in `false`.

A neat trick to avoid such problem is to use `std::tie` and make use of `std::tuple::operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const Point &other) const {
    return std::tie(m_x,m_y) < std::tie(other.m_x,other.m_y);
}
```